# extending logical partition using the unallocated space in the extended partition

Tags: partitioning

I have some unallocated space in the beginning of my extended partition which is right after my logical partition. Now I need to extend my logical partition using that unallocated space of the extended partition. I am unable to do with either windows disk management utility or even gparted. How shall I proceed? Help me.

The following image may give a better understanding.
[image] 
Now, what I wanna do is to increase the size of **/dev/sda2**. I thought that I could expand it to the unallocated space visible inside **/dev/sda3**. I'm failing in it. That is what I have said above this pic.

---

**Update:**
I have tried doing it by using gparted from a ubuntu liveusb. While attempting that way, my hard disk wasn't mounted by default. The image below may be a proof for it. Even by that way, gparted showed no option to extend **/dev/sda2** 
[image]

Comment: I found gparted quite limited.. and windows disk management may be too. Try Easeus partition manager and/or paragon partition wizard. They are free. And if you want to do an image, then use macrium reflect.

Comment: What is the size of this *"unallocated space"*?  "Cylinder alignment" will sometimes force the creation of unallocated sectors between partitions.

Comment: @sawdust: I did create the unallocated space since I needed it. It is about 18 GiB.

Comment: Was the partition dismounted at the time?  This should be a piece of cake for gparted.  Just for clarification, the logical partition is within an extended partition.  It isn't clear from your question if that's what you are describing.  Is the free space to the left or right of the one you want to expand?

Comment: @Ramvignesh: Have you looked into Clonezilla (as noted in the answer below)? Granted a little more work, but it might resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If gparted won't do it for you, you could try Clonezilla. I believe you'll need to first copy the partition(s) in question off the disk onto another device and then back, but Clonezilla may allow you to copy in place. Once copied off the disk, you can delete your extended partion and resize your logical (perhaps that should be primary) partition with gparted. Then recreate your extended partition and logical partion(s) within it and copy back your logical partitions. Probably best to backup partitions with software your comfortable with. Clonezilla would work but if this is the first time using it you might want to use something you've used before.